# Captcha refreshing in PHP form

Tags: php

I'm trying to use the Securimage PHP script (cf google) for CAPTCHA's but I have a problem: when I press the link "Different image" (to display another captcha), I lose all the text that was entered in the fields of my PHP form. So a user would have to re-enter everything again, which is problematic.

Here is the code.
Note: I took away the '#' for the href because for some reason, it fails in changing the captcha image. Does anyone know why? (this happens in both Safari and Firefox)

```
<img id='captcha' src='/myproject/securimage/securimage_show.php' alt='CAPTCHA Image' /><br> <a href='' onclick='document.getElementById('captcha').src =  '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false'> [Different Image ]</a>
```

Comment: can you post the rest of your form code?

Comment: This happens because page is refreshed, right?

Comment: better try google's recaptcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have removed '#' from href thats why whole page is refreshed when the link is clicked and all fields data is lost. don't remove it, and then use following code

```
<img id='captcha' src='/myproject/securimage/securimage_show.php' alt='CAPTCHA Image' />
<br> 
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src =  '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false;"> [Different Image ]</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of removing the '#'. The page reloads because you used the wrong quotes within the `<a>` tag. When using single quotes `'` for the html attribute as well as the containing javascript inside `onclick`, the browser will only use `document.getElementById(` for the onclick event. The `return false;` will not be executed and the page reloads.

You may always use `"` for html attributes and `'` for javascript. Or escape the same quotes inside attrbiutes with a `\`.

This will work also without '#':

```
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false;"> [Different Image ]</a>
```

Or the escaped version of it:

```
<a href='' onclick='document.getElementById(\'captcha\').src = \'/securimage/securimage_show.php?\' + Math.random(); return false;'> [Different Image ]</a>
```